# Why AlertDialog show when I do not want

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I show AlertDialog  in AlarmManager. DialogNotification (Alert dialog) - Activity, in manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".notification.DialogNotification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog_notification"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
```

I want dialogue to show up even when the program is not running, but when i go to app, dialog show in Splash Screen, but i do not call him. How i can fix it?

```
public class DialogNotification extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("Log", "onCreate DialogNotification");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.time_to_call_your_clients)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(DialogNotification.this, SplashActivity.class);
                        startActivity(notificationIntent);
                        dialog.cancel();
                        DialogNotification.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        DialogNotification.this.finish();
                    }
                }).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you're calling the dialog on onCreate. It will be shown everytime you open the app

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the .show() call.... it should be pretty obvious when you see the stack and what function you are in....

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your statement "I want dialogue to show up even when the program is not running" because if the program is not running, I'm not quite sure how the dialogue is supposed to show up. Also, without understanding your program flow, I can't pinpoint exactly where the problem is.

That being said, here is my guess. If you are seeing this event when you get to the DialogNotification Activity, then the problem may be the fact that you're creating a new `AlertDialog.Builder` each time you call "onCreate".

If you want to have a single `AlertDialog` instance, then you might want to add a conditional statment (if statement) to ensure you want to create a new `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem! I start service which start DialogActivity, in method `onStartCommand` was:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //some code 
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

It is not right solution!

It is right solution:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //some code 
    stopSelf();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```